# Discord BOT - DM someone that leaves server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know that it is possible to DM someone with the bot if you have their ID, but how can I get the users ID's when they enter the server?

I was thinking:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
or
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
   user = await client.fetch_user(**the id**) 
   await user.send("Your message")
```

Comment: how about `memeber.send()` in `on_member_leave()` ?

Comment: discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

Comment: I've done                                                                                                              `async def on_member_remove(member):
    user = await client.fetch_user(member.id)
    print(member.id)
    print(user)
    await user.send(
        f'We hope that you had fun!'
    )`                                                                                                                                       and even that throws the same error, even though the member.id and user are right!

Comment: as for me if someone leaves server then it can be too late to send anything - it can be already disconnected when you get event and you can't access this user.

Comment: Bot needs to share a guild to send DM's to a User like @furas said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `fetch_user`, you can simply use `message.send` -

```
@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
   await member.send("Your message")
```

Also, if the member has no server common with the client or if the member has disabled direct messages, The message will not be sent.

Comment: be careful user is not defined. It should be member.

Comment: oops, my bad, I did not cross check my answer, thanks for pointing that out :>